# compare indexes of lists and check the conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

am trying to compare index of one list with the second list.

```
s = [20,40,600,800,1000]
e = [30,700,900,1100]
```

In the above example Ill check if both the lengths match or not, if not match, i want to see the index which was missing, like in above case, i want to ignore 4 .

here, s will always be less than e when compared index wise, but it goes like this.

`s[0]<e[0]<s[1]<e[1]<s[2]`....

Output expected :

```
s = [20,600,800,1000]
e = [30,700,900,1100]
```

Few more samples:

given:

```
x = [2,4,6,8,10]
y = [7,9,11]
```

expected :

```
x = [6,8,10]
y = [7,9,11]
```

Given:

```
a = [4,6,8,10]
b = [3,5,7,9,11]
```

expected :

```
a = [4,6,8,10]
b = [5,7,9,11]
```

Need some inputs.

Code:

```
if len(s) != len(e):
    if len(s)>len(e):
        for index in range(len(s)):
            if s[index]<e[index]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate ' if not match, i want to see the index which was missing, like in above case, i want to ignore 4' statement. How 4 gets ignored?

Comment: Actually, also ignoring 6 the condition is met. What is the rule in cases like these? Ignoring the first index?

Comment: You could take the minimum from each list - then for each number if the number minus the minimum is not equivalent then its not a match -- A caveat would be if your minuum value is the odd one out.

Comment: `for index in range(len(s)):
            if s[index]<e[index]` in this way you will go out of bounds for `e` array.

Comment: I see that `s[0]<e[0]<s[1]<e[1]<s[2]....` is not the only one condition. The arrays must have the same progression, right? So that  `s [i] - s [i-1] = e [i]-e [i-1]`

Comment: @all , I want my output array to be equal length and the condition should satisfy `s[0]<e[0]<s[1]<e[1]<s[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
i = j = 0
q, w = [], []

while i < len(e) and j < len(s):
    if e[i] > s[j]:
        w.append(e[i])
        q.append(s[j])
        while j < len(s) and e[i] > s[j]:
            q[-1] = s[j]
            j += 1
    i += 1

print(q,w)
```

Comment: This works like a charm, am still testing it with few conditions, so far so good.

Comment: hey, e[j] - s[i] ! = 1, this will fail, this wont be one always

Comment: I have edited the `s` and `e`, can you please check

Comment: What is condition then? `e[0] > s[0]`, but `s[1] > e[0]`?

Comment: yes exactly.. thats the condition that I have mentioned, `s[0]<e[0]<s[1]<e[1]<s[2]`

Comment: and the difference between them has to be a power of 10? Since in your edited example 700 > 40

Comment: Modified it a little

Comment: hey no, the difference shouldnt be power of 10... 
can you try with this... `s = [20,40,65,83,97]
e = [30,80,86,100]`

Comment: expected output : `s = [20,65,83,97]
e = [30,80,86,100]`

Comment: I guess you were close, can you please try with the above sample ?

Comment: And one more try, hopefully the last

Comment: this is working if len(s) > len(e), i guess ill try it out for len(e)>len(s)

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216035/discussion-between-alexander-lekontsev-and-pylearner).